# how to run delphi application on a linux webserver shared hosting?

Tags: javascript, php, delphi, delphi-xe2, delphi-2010

im trying to convert a delphi code to webpage but the result is not the same. 
i tried to find some soft that convert delphi into webpage but i have find only for windows server, and the problem is i need to run this script on a linux server that is only a shared hosting so i don't have access to the root to use wine or other simulators so i can use only php script or javascript

delphi code :

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1Change(Sender: TObject);
var
  str2 : string;
 key  : TStringList;
 i: integer;
begin
   key := TStringList.create;

  for i := 0 To pred(length(edit1.Text)) do

      begin
        str2 := IntTostr(StrToInt(Copy(trim(edit1.Text),i, 1)) + 5);
        if (Length(str2) = 1)
        then
           key.Add(str2)
        else
         key.Add(Copy(str2,1, 1));
            end ;
      edit2.Text := key.Text;
    end;
```

html code :

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML SYSTEM>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function magic() {
    var src = document.getElementById('src');
    var dst = document.getElementById('dst');

    var str = src.value;
    var key = '';

    var len = str.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        key += str[len - i - 1];
    }

    dst.value = key;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="src">
<button onclick="magic()">Convert</button>
<input type="text" id="dst">
</body>
```

the result must be for : 0123456789 = 5678901234

Best Regards

Comment: If you are interested in porting your Delphi based code into a web based application then I believe the best bet would be to use Smart Mobile Studio (http://smartmobilestudio.com/) whose purpose is making HTML5 based web application from Pascal based code. However do note that porting your Delphi code to SMS would probably require a little more than simply copy pasting your Delphi code as there are some differences between Delphi and SMS Pascal dialects which you would need to overcome. But I guess it would be most easy to begin with.

Comment: As for directly running Delphi applications on Linux. According to Embarcadero roadmap (http://community.embarcadero.com/article/news/16211-embarcadero-rad-studio-2016-product-approach-and-roadmap-2) we should be expecting Linux server support added sometime toward the end of the year.

Comment: thank you very much i have download mobile studio yesterday and i tried it and but i don't know how to run the code, i have create a temple and when i run the code i have a blank screen as you see in this pictures 
http://imgur.com/a/tDsp5

Comment: Write an emulator in PHP or Javascript would seem to be your option. That is unless you come to your senses and port the 10 lines of Delphi code to PHP or Javascript.

Comment: @SilverWarior: he does not need to wait for Embarcadero(Idera) to support Linux. There is Lazarus, Delphi alike environment which supports Linux for sure.
Bouhlal: with Lazarus your code won't need many changes and you can run it in Linux.

Comment: for lazarus i can compile the program from windows machine to linux or i must install it on linux machine?

Comment: it is possible to use JavaScript String replace() ?
example :
when i type 0 it is replaced with 5
and when type 1 replaced with 6 ....

Comment: i have this code:

begin
s := Edit1.Text;
for i := 1 to Length(s) do
  s[i] := Chr(Ord('0') + (Ord(s[i]) - Ord('0') + 5) mod 10);
  edit2.Text:=s;
end;

i tried to convert it to php but didn't work

$count = count(num1);
for ($i=1; $i<$count(num1); $i++) {
echo " chr = ".chr(ord('0')).  +   ord($num1[$i]).  - Ord('0') +(5) ."<br>";

}

}

Comment: @smooty86 The reason why I didn't suggest FreePascal/Lazarus is because OP claims he is interested in converting VCL application to webpage (Web Application) and not just porting Windows based application to Linux for which Lazarus would currently be best option.

Comment: @SilverWarior - That was just a response to your EMBT roadmap. He can give it a try than wait.

Comment: @Bouhlal: Well, it is probably easier to run a virtual machine with Linux. But yes, it should be possible to cross compile the code on Windows and get Linux (I don't like to mention it but there is CodeTyphoon project which is some kind of distribution of Lazarus and there is cross-compilation integrated into the installation)

Comment: @SilverWarior
i have make put this code in php :
$S = '123456';
for ($i=1; $i < strlen($S); $i++) {
echo " chr = ".(chr(ord('0')). + (ord('$S[$i]'). - Ord('0') +(5)) % 10) ."<br>";
}
}

but it give the result :
chr = 01
chr = 01
chr = 01
chr = 01
chr = 01 
 normaly its has to be 678901 

the original delphi code is :
 begin
s := Edit1.Text;
for i := 1 to Length(s) do
s[i] := Chr(Ord('0') + (Ord(s[i]) - Ord('0') + 5) mod 10);
edit2.Text:=s;
end;

Comment: @smooty86
any idea about this script?


  .

Comment: If your script does not work as you want, then you have to change it. Nobody else will do it instead of you. You have to put exact question and you will get a reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the working code

```
$test = $num1;

$result = $test;
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($test); $i++) {
    $result[$i] = ($test[$i] + 5) % 10;
}
```